# How to get a list of multiple emails from a string by using split in Java?

Tags: java, email

I have this string that contains a bunch of emails in it:

> " email1@gmail.com , 'email2@gmail.com,email3@gmail.com,
>   email4@gmail.com' , 'email5@gmail.com ,email6@gmail.com' "

So what I'm trying to do is extract each email from each substring and end up with an array that contains all those email:

Example:

> String[] myArray = {email1@gmail.com , email2@gmail.com,
>   email3@gmail.com, email4@gmail.com, email5@gmail.com};

Here's my code:

```
String str = "email1@gmail.com , 'email2@gmail.com,email3@gmail.com, email4@gmail.com' , 'email5@gmail.com ,email6@gmail.com'";

    String[] newArray = str.split(",");
     for(int i = 0 ; i < newArray.length; i++) 
        {
        if(newArray[i].contains(",")) 
         {
            newArray = newArray[i].split(",");
         }
        }
```

Keep in mind that a subString may have multiple emails in it.

Comment: For one thing, since you're using `newAray each time`, you're losing the previous values whenever there is a substring ...

Comment: @AntonH any ideas how to solve the issue? Thank you

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: @lexicore the problem is that I'm struggling on getting all of the emails inside an array :(. you think a while loop will do it?

Comment: There are several possibilities. One would be to use temporary arrays and then put the result of those splits into another, final array. Another possibility is to have a recursive method that returns the result of a substring. Really depends on what you want, on how sure you are of the format of the string.

Comment: a recursive way will do it, but I'm not sure how to implement it

Comment: To be honest, you might be able to do just one split, and then have a single loop to clear up the resulting strings (remove single quotes, whitespaces, etc.), since you have only one string and not an array of strings.

Comment: Split on ",", check if first or last char is a ' and if yes remove it and trim() the string. Regex would work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Pattern matching and regex, a simple email follows : `\w+@\w+.com`  : `multipleWordCharacter@multipleWordCharacter.com`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "email1@gmail.com,'email2@gmail.com,email3@gmail.com, email4@gmail.com'" +
            ", 'email5@gmail.com ,email6@gmail.com'";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w+@\\w+.com").matcher(str);
    List<String> emailsList = new ArrayList<>();

    while (m.find()){
        emailsList.add(m.group());
    }

    String[]emailsArray = emailsList.toArray(new String[0]);  // if really need an array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(emailsArray));
}
```

I used a List at first because it's very easy to add element dunamiclly, you can't with an array, but at the, end you still can use an array with the code I wrote

---

And this will print :

```
[email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com, email3@gmail.com, email4@gmail.com, email5@gmail.com, email6@gmail.com]
```

---

[`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/lORn2G/1) & 
[`Code demo`](https://ideone.com/FrvJpw)

Comment: can you please add you curly braces {} for  your while loop so I know where it ends?

Comment: @progx done ;) when there is not, ony the next instruction if in the loop , think about accept the answer if i satisfies you ;)

Comment: @prox would this work if instead of comma(,) I have semi-colon (;) ?

Comment: I'll add a  demo, for you can see that it works with lots of things

Comment: Word of warning. This doesn't account for other suffixes like .net. Nor does it account for "My Email" <my.email@fin.net> to be fully RFC 5322 compliant you need a bit more logic.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do?:

```
String noQuotesStr = str.replace("'", ""); //removes '
String[] newArray = noQuotesStr.split(",");
```